# PHP using inner function variable in another function

Tags: php

I tried this code today! But it's not giving the output I expected.. this is my code..

```
<?php

namePrint('Rajitha');

function namePrint($name) { 
  echo $name;
}

wrap('tobaco');

function wrap($txt) {
  global $name;
  echo "Your username is ".$name." ".$txt."";
}

?>
```

This code will print on screen

```
RajithaYour username is tobaco
```

but I want to get

```
RajithaRajithaYour username is tobaco
```

My question is: why is the $name variable in the wrap function not working?

Thanks.

Comment: Whats the point to `namePrint`? Why not just `echo`?

Comment: this is a sample structure of my complex code I want to get work $name variable in wrap() function

Comment: Shouldn't the expected output be `RajithaYour username is Rajitha tobaco`?

Comment: sorry , Yeh! it is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use `echo` inside function to output the result. And never use `global` for variables.

You used `echo` inside function and because of that you get unexpected output.

```
echo namePrint('Rajitha');

function namePrint($name){ 
    return $name;
}

echo wrap('tobaco');

function wrap($txt){
    //global $name;
    return "Your username is ".namePrint('Rajitha')." ".$txt."";
}
```

### Output

using echo in function [Codepad](http://codepad.org/yTZDhRyz)

```
RajithaRajithaYour username is  tobaco
```

### Output1

using return in function [Codepad](http://codepad.org/aw2MoQU3)

```
RajithaYour username is Rajitha tobaco
```

Comment: OMG this is the answer, what Im looking for.. Thankyou verymuch sir!

Comment: oh! didnt downvote your answer.. I marked your answer as the correct one. thanks

Comment: @NadlerBanit I am not saying to you, it is for that person who downvoted. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wrap a function around another you could simply pass a closure as one of the arguments:

```
function wrap($fn, $txt)
{
    echo "Your username is ";
    $fn();
    echo ' ' . $txt;
}

wrap(function() {
    namePrint('Rajitha');
}, 'tobaco');
```

This construct is very delicate; using function return values is more reliable:

```
function getFormattedName($name) { 
    return $name;
}

echo getFormattedName('Jack');
```

Then, the wrap function:

```
function wrap($fn, $txt)
{
    return sprintf("Your username is %s %s", $fn(), $txt);
}

echo wrap(function() {
    return getFormattedName('Jack');
}, 'tobaco');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to pass $name as a parameter to the wrap function.

```
<?php

$name = 'Rajitha';

function namePrint($name){ 
    echo $name;
}

function wrap($txt, $name){
    echo "Your username is " . $name . " ". $txt;
}

namePrint($name);

wrap('tobaco', $name);

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

$name should be declared and initialized as global variable.then you can the output you need.

The code should look like this.

```
<?php
$name = 'Rajitha';
namePrint($name);

function namePrint($name){ 
    echo $name;
}

wrap('tobaco');

function wrap($txt){
     global $name;
     echo "Your username is ".$name." ".$txt."";
}

?>
```

Comment: Everything that works does not necessarily mean good. This answer is misguiding for future readers because it uses `global`.